# XeTeX wasn't built when cross-compiling TeXLive

Tags: texlive, cross-platform

I'd like to cross compile TeXLive on a Arch Linux build system for the host and target MIPS. I have set up a correct MIPS compiling toolchain (OpenWRT SDK).

I get TeXLive source through

`rsync -a --delete --exclude=.svn tug.org::tldevsrc/Build/source/ .`

and get it manually configured by

`./configure --enable-multiplatform --disable-native-texlive-build --prefix=PREFIX --with-fontconfig-includes=INCDIR --with-fontconfig-libdir=LIBDIR --enable-build-in-source-tree --target=mipsel-openwrt-linux --host=mipsel-openwrt-linux --build=x86_64-pc-linux`

with paths like `INCDIR` `LIBDIR` and `PREFIX` are set correctly then `make && make world`.

All is fine except some `web2c` programs like `xetex` isn't built.

I'd like to ask how to configure it to make it compile `xetex`?
I've tested with `--enable-xetex` but it doesn't work actually.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it fail to compile (in that case, have you checked that you have the dependencies like harfbuzz for that platform) or does it not even try to compile xetex?

Comment: @TeXnician After I `configure` in web2c, I found some warnings. "using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet" and "Sorry, neither ApplicationServices framework nor fontconfig library: disabling xetex", but I have set up correct fontconfig (compiled for target) path. It means that `xetex` is not even tried.

Comment: This is probably better asked on the TeX Live mailing list: http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live